# Pulling multiple rows from a CSV if 1 parameter is met and saving to a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has multiple rows and columns and I am trying to pull the entire row if the parameter in the third column matches. Such as:

name, age, DOB,   location

x,45,01/01/01, Japan

u,76,05/04/03, United States

My end goal would be to find anybody with a birthdate between dates A and dates B, and pull their entire information and put it in a new CSV. I am newish to python and am just getting into some more serious elements of it, rather than just the basic if else statements. What is the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `pandas` for this purpose. You can load the csv file like this:

```
import pandas

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', parse_dates=['DOB']) # parse the dates in the DOB column to datetime format
df = df.sort_values(by='DOB', ascending=True) # sort by dates, just to be sure
```

This outputs:

|  | name | age | DOB | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | 45 | 2001-01-01 00:00:00 | Japan |
| 1 | u | 76 | 2003-05-04 00:00:00 | United States |

You can now filter the dataframe by a single day using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['DOB'] == "2001-01-01"]
```

Or by a range of days:

```
start_date = '2000-01-12'
end_date = '2002-01-23'
df.loc[df['DOB'].between(start_date,end_date, inclusive=False)] # set inclusive to True if you wish to include the start and end date in your search
```

To save the output to a new csv file you can use [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
filtered_df = df.loc[df['DOB'] == "2001-01-01"] # or use the range alternative
filtered_df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```